# Product between all combinations of a vector's elements

Tags: r, vector, combinations, multiplication

Suppose I have a vector `c(1, 2, 3, 4)` with no duplicated values. I need a vector `c(1 * 2, 1 * 3, 1 * 4, 2 * 3, 2 * 4, 3 * 4)`, so the multiplication is done in all possible combinations of this vector's values. Is there a way of doing that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `combn(1:4, 2, FUN = function(x) x[1] * x[2])`

Comment: or you could do `combn(1:4, 2, prod)`

Comment: @李哲源 I am still curious why `"*"` is not working

Comment: @akrun@李哲源@Onyambu you guys are so awesome, I tried akrun's code and it worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @BenZ Another option would be `outer` plus extracting the upper/lower triangular part, i.e. `m <- outer(c(1, 2, 3, 4), c(1, 2, 3, 4)); as.numeric(m[upper.tri(m)])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `combn` with anonymous function call

```
combn(vec, 2, FUN = function(x) x[1] * x[2])
#[1]  2  3  4  6  8 12
```

#### data

```
vec <- 1:4
```

Answer (score 5):

This is fun enough. I thought `combn(1:4, 2, "*")` would be the simplest solution but it actually does not work. We have to use `combn(1:4, 2, prod)` [as Onyambu commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52086098/multiply-each-value-in-a-vector-in-turns-by-the-values-next-to-it-in-r/52086291#comment91122607_52086098). The issue is: in an *"N choose K"* setting, `FUN` must be able to take a vector of length-K as input. `"*"` is not the right one.

```
## K = 2 case
"*"(c(1, 2))  ## this is different from: "*"(1, 2)
#Error in *c(1, 2) : invalid unary operator

prod(c(1, 2))
#[1] 2
```

---

#### We are going too far, but we will meet this sooner or later

Thanks [Maurits Evers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52086394/4891738) for elaboration on `outer` / `lower.tri` / `upper.tri`. Here is an adapted way to avoid generating those temporary matrices from `outer` and `*****.tri`:

```
tri_ind <- function (n, lower= TRUE, diag = FALSE) {
  if (diag) {
    tmp <- n:1
    j <- rep.int(1:n, tmp)
    i <- sequence(tmp) - 1L + j
    } else {
    tmp <- (n-1):1
    j <- rep.int(1:(n-1), tmp)
    i <- sequence(tmp) + j
    }
  if (lower) list(i = i, j = j)
  else list(i = j, j = i)
  }

vec <- 1:4
ind <- tri_ind(length(vec), FALSE, FALSE)
#$i
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 3
#
#$j
#[1] 2 3 4 3 4 4

vec[ind[[1]]] * vec[ind[[2]]]
#[1]  2  3  4  6  8 12
```

The `tri_ind` function is wrapper of [my this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40139629/4891738). It could be used as a fast and memory-efficient alternative for `combn(length(vec), 2)` or its `outer`-equivalence.

Originally I linked an [`finv`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39006382/4891738) function but it is not good for benchmarking, as it is designed for extracting a few elements from a "dist" object (a collapsed lower triangular matrix). If all elements of the triangular matrix are referenced, its index computation actually imposes unnecessary overhead. `tri_ind` is a better option.

```
library(bench)
```

**benchmark index generation**

```
bench1 <- function (n) {
  bench::mark("combn" = combn(n, 2),
              "tri_ind" = tri_ind(n, TRUE, FALSE),
              "upper.tri" = which(upper.tri(matrix(0, n, n)), arr.ind = TRUE),
              check = FALSE)
  }

## for small problem, `tri_ind` is already the fastest
bench1(100)
#  expression      min     mean  median      max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc n_itr
#  <chr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:t> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <dbl> <int>
#1 combn        11.6ms   11.9ms  11.9ms  12.59ms      83.7    39.1KB     9    32
#2 tri_ind     189.3µs  205.9µs 194.6µs   4.82ms    4856.     60.4KB    21  1888
#3 upper.tri   618.4µs  635.8µs 624.1µs 968.36µs    1573.    411.7KB    57   584

## `tri_ind` is 10x faster than `upper.tri`, and 100x faster than `combn`
bench1(5000)
#  expression      min     mean   median      max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc
#  <chr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <dbl>
#1 combn         30.6s    30.6s    30.6s    30.6s    0.0327    95.4MB   242
#2 tri_ind    231.98ms 259.31ms 259.31ms 286.63ms    3.86     143.3MB     0
#3 upper.tri     3.02s    3.02s    3.02s    3.02s    0.332    953.6MB     4
```

**benchmark on OP's problem**

```
bench2 <- function (n) {
  vec <- numeric(n)
  bench::mark("combn" = combn(vec, 2, prod),
              "tri_ind" = {ind <- tri_ind(n, FALSE, FALSE);
                           vec[ind[[1]]] * vec[ind[[2]]]},
              "upper.tri" = {m <- outer(vec, vec);                                
                             c(m[upper.tri(m)])},
              check = FALSE)
  }

bench2(100)
#  expression      min     mean  median      max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc n_itr
#  <chr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:t> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <dbl> <int>
#1 combn        18.6ms   19.2ms  19.1ms  20.55ms      52.2    38.7KB     4    22
#2 tri_ind     386.9µs  432.3µs 395.6µs   7.58ms    2313.    176.6KB     1  1135
#3 upper.tri   326.9µs  488.5µs 517.6µs 699.07µs    2047.      336KB     0  1024

bench2(5000)
#  expression      min     mean   median     max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc n_itr
#  <chr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <dbl> <int>
#1 combn        48.13s   48.13s   48.13s  48.13s    0.0208    95.3MB   204     1
#2 tri_ind     861.7ms  861.7ms  861.7ms 861.7ms    1.16     429.3MB     0     1
#3 upper.tri     1.95s    1.95s    1.95s   1.95s    0.514    810.6MB     3     1
```

For me, it is interesting to know that `combn` is not written in compiled code. It actually has an R-level for loop inside. The various alternatives is just trying to speed it up in *"N choose 2"* case without writing compiled code.

**Better choice??**

Function `combinations` from `gtools` package uses recursive algorithm, which is problematic for big problem size. Function `combn` from `combinat` package does not use compiled code so it is no better than `combn` from R core. The `RcppAlgos` package by [Joseph Wood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4408538/joseph-wood) has a `comboGenearl` function which is the fastest one I see so far.

```
library(RcppAlgos)

## index generation
bench3 <- function (n) {
  bench::mark("tri_ind" = tri_ind(n, FALSE, FALSE),
              "Joseph" = comboGeneral(n, 2), check = FALSE)
  }

bench3(5000)
#  expression      min     mean   median     max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc n_itr
#  <chr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <dbl> <int>
#1 tri_ind       290ms    297ms    297ms   303ms      3.37   143.4MB     4     2
#2 Joseph        134ms    155ms    136ms   212ms      6.46    95.4MB     2     4

## on OP's problem
bench4 <- function (n) {
  vec <- numeric(n)
  bench::mark("tri_ind" = {ind <- tri_ind(n, FALSE, FALSE);
                           vec[ind[[1]]] * vec[ind[[2]]]},
              "Joseph" = comboGeneral(vec, 2, constraintFun = "prod", keepResults = TRUE),
              check = FALSE)
  }

bench4(5000)
#  expression      min     mean   median     max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc n_itr
#  <chr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <dbl> <int>
#1 tri_ind       956ms    956ms    956ms   956ms      1.05     429MB     3     1
#2 Joseph        361ms    362ms    362ms   363ms      2.76     286MB     1     2
```

---

Joseph Wood has various answers on combinations / permutations. For example: [Faster version of combn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51005669/4891738).

Comment: You actually need to set `keepResults = TRUE` in order to actually carry out the multiplication. E.g. `comboGeneral(vec, 2, constraintFun = "prod", keepResults = TRUE)`. Nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the "`outer` + upper triangular part option"

```
m <- outer(1:4, 1:4)
as.numeric(m[upper.tri(m)])
#[1]  2  3  6  4  8 12
```

Another method is to index the elements of the upper/lower triangular part of a matrix directly and then calculate the pairwise product for those elements (adapted from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36158638/outer-function-in-r-for-upper-triangular-matrix))

```
upperouter <- function(x) {
    N <- length(x)
    i <- sequence(1:N)
    j <- rep(1:N, 1:N)
    (1:N)[i[i != j]] * (1:N)[j[j != i]]
}
upperouter(1:4)
#[1]  2  3  6  4  8 12
```

---

### Benchmark analysis

It's interesting to compare the different methods in a `microbenchmark` analysis for a larger `vector` (e.g. `1:100`):

```
upperouter <- function(x) {
    N <- length(x)
    i <- sequence(1:N)
    j <- rep(1:N, 1:N)
    (1:N)[i[i != j]] * (1:N)[j[j != i]]
}

finv <- function (n) {
  k <- 1:(n * (n - 1) / 2)
  j <- floor(((2 * n + 1) - sqrt((2 * n - 1) ^ 2 - 8 * (k - 1))) / 2)
  i <- j + k - (2 * n - j) * (j - 1) / 2
  cbind(i, j)
  }


N <- 100
library(microbenchmark)
res <- microbenchmark(
    combn  = combn(1:N, 2, prod),
    outer = {
        m <- outer(1:N, 1:N)
        as.numeric(m[upper.tri(m)])
    },
    upperouter = {
        upperouter(1:N)
    },
    finv = {
        vec <- 1:N
        ind <- finv(length(vec))
        vec[ind[, 2]] * vec[ind[, 1]]
    },
    sapply = {
        m <- sapply(1:N, "*", 1:N)
        as.numeric(m[upper.tri(m)])
    })
res
#Unit: microseconds
#       expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#      combn 6584.938 6896.0545 7584.8084 7035.9575 7886.5720 12020.626   100
#      outer  106.791  113.6535  157.3774  138.9205  160.5985   950.706   100
# upperouter  201.943  210.1515  277.0989  227.6370  259.1975  2806.962   100
#       finv  308.447  324.1960  442.3220  332.7250  375.3490  4128.325   100
#     sapply  232.805  249.9080  298.3674  283.8580  315.9145   556.463   100

library(ggplot2)
autoplot(res)
```

[image]

Comment: This is similar to `(1:4%o%1:4)[lower.tri(diag(4))]`

Comment: wht about if you use `sapply` instead of `outer`? will the benchmark be the same still?? ie `m=sapply(1:4,"*",1:4)`??

Comment: @李哲源 I've updated my post to include another option using a function `upperouter` to index the elements of the upper/lower triangular matrix directly. Please take a look.

Comment: @Onyambu `sapply` clocks in similarly to `outer`/`finv` with `sapply` (see my update).