# Compute all possible slopes between two points

Tags: r, performance

I have two vectors

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
```

I need to compute the slopes between all points(formula: y2 - y1/ x2 - x1). So I need the slope between points `(x1, y1)` and `(x1, y2)`, `(x1, y1)` and `(x1, y3)`..., (x2, y2) and (y2, y3) etc. In total it will be `choose(n, 2)` slopes.

How to do that in R **efficiently** (i need to run this many times, so efficiency is really important here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need `choose(n, 2)` slopes between `n` number of `(x, y)` points, use

```
xy <- cbind(x, y)
library(RcppAlgos)
ind <- comboGeneral(nrow(xy), 2)
d <- xy[ind[, 2], ] - xy[ind[, 1], ]
slope <- d[, 2] / d[, 1]
```

I am not using `combn` function from R core. See [Product between all combinations of a vector's elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52086098/4891738) for a case study.

Answer (score 1):

Using the data in the Note at the end and assuming n choose 2 slopes are wanted.

```
slopes <- c(combn(y, 2, diff) / combn(x, 2, diff))
slopes
## [1] -3.7970202 -1.4062612 -3.8066222 -3.1325626 -0.9648338 -3.8171698
## [7] -2.5220191 -0.3885287 -0.5732387  4.1033272
```

These are the slopes of these pairs respectively:

```
nms <- combn(n, 2, paste, collapse = ":")
nms
## [1] "1:2" "1:3" "1:4" "1:5" "2:3" "2:4" "2:5" "3:4" "3:5" "4:5"

all.equal(slopes, slopes2[order(nms2)])
```

### ADDED

If that is not fast enough try `combnPrim` from gRBase (in Bioconductor) instead:

```
library(gRBase)

xx <- combnPrim(x, 2)
yy <- combnPrim(y, 2)
slopes2 <- (yy[2, ] - yy[1, ]) / (xx[2, ] - xx[1, ])
slopes2
## [1] -3.7970202 -1.4062612 -0.9648338 -3.8066222 -3.8171698 -0.3885287
## [7] -3.1325626 -2.5220191 -0.5732387  4.1033272

nms2 <- apply(combnPrim(n, 2), 2, paste, collapse = ":")
## [1] "1:2" "1:3" "2:3" "1:4" "2:4" "3:4" "1:5" "2:5" "3:5" "4:5"

all.equal(slopes, slopes2[order(nms2)])
## [1] TRUE
```

### Note

We use the following input:

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 5
x <- rnorm(n)
y <- rnorm(n)
```